# Find common items in two lists

Tags: c#, list

My problem is that I need to compare two lists and find amount of objects that share same field's value. Kind a find common objects of two lists, or some join operation. I don't want to use Linq as later I'd need access to indexes of elements, but for now the classes/methods are simplified.
Class Pip:

```
public class Pip{
    public CONTROLLER.COLORS Color;
}
```

Simplified class Sequence that is basically list of pips

```
public class Sequence{
    private List<Pip> pips = new List<Pip>();

    public Sequence(Pip[] pips)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pips.Length; i++)
        {
            addPip(pips[i]);
        }
    }
    public List<Pip> getPips()
    {
        return pips;
    }
}
```

So now I have this method which shall return me amount of pips of the same color for two sequences, where each pip is of some color.

```
private int getMatchedColors(Sequence lockSeq, Sequence checkSeq)
{
    List<Pip> lockPips = lockSeq.getPips();
    List<Pip> checkPips = checkSeq.getPips();
    List<Pip> excludedPips = new List<Pip>(lockPips.Count);
    int matchedColors = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lockPips.Count; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < checkPips.Count; j++)
            if (checkPips[i].Color == lockPips[j].Color && !excludedPips.Contains(lockPips[j]))
            {
                matchedColors++;
                excludedPips.Add(lockPips[j]);
                break;
            }
    return matchedColors;
}
```

The logic begin my reason is next.
Take each element of `lockPips` list and compare current pip's color to current color of `checkPips`' list pip. If match occurs we check if matched `lockPips`' current pip has already been checked. If not then we increment counter and add `lockPips`' current pip to list of `checkedPips` thus making sure that it will be skipped at next check.

Debugging shows that `excludedPips` list already contains the pip that has been checked for the first time and it uses its color at every check thus making algorithm skipping all the instructions in "if" statement.

> Examples: lockPips:  RED, GREEN, GREEN checkPips: RED, GREEN, GREEN
>   expected matchedColors: 3 actual matchedColors:   1 (RED)
>
> lockPips:  BLUE, BLUE, BLUE checkPips: BLUE, BLUE, RED expected
>   matchedColors: 2 actual matchedColors:   1 (BLUE)

So the result at any actual `matchedColors` > 0 is 1.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to write your own logic for this purpose because you can get your desired result by using the LINQ and `Intersect` method. Like this:

```
List<Pip> excludedPips = lockPips.Intersect(checkPips).ToList();
```

And also in your class:

```
public class Pip
{
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Pip))
            return false;
        Pip p = (Pip)obj;
        return (p.Color == Color);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}", Color).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Or if you want to get the common corresponding elements of two List use [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<Pip> excludedPips = lockPips.Zip(checkPips , (f,s) => f.Color == s.Color ? f : null)
                                  .Where(c => c!= null).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
List<Pip> Matches = new List<Pip>(L1);

// Get the matches
Matches.AddRange(L2.Except(Matches));
Matches.RemoveAll(pip=> !L2.Contains(pip));
```

Then whenever you want to find the original index of your desired pip in Matches do something like this

```
List<int> indexes = new List<int>();

if (L1.Contains(desiredPip)) indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, L1.Count).Where(i => L1[i].Color == desiredPip.Color).ToList();

if (L2.Contains(desiredPip)) indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, L2.Count).Where(i => L2[i].Color == desiredPip.Color).ToList();
```

I know you said you didn't want to use LINQ but if your only reason is that you want to access the indexes this solves that problem.